# Why does c^2 appear in E=mc^2?

Tags: mass-energy

I always wondered what relevance the speed of light has in a formula that describes the relationship between energy and mass.

I always think of c as a line/vector, and c^2 as a plane, but that does not get me any further.

Does it give us some insight on what happens when this transformation occurs?

Comment: Why would $c$ be a line and $c^2$ a plane? The speed of light is a constant that appears in the equations as nature relate the two quantities numerically so (and likewise for all the other constants in the universe).

Answer (score 2):

In the context of $E=mc^2$, it's pretty irrelevant that $c$ is the speed of light. It just so happens that photons, being massless, travel at the maximum speed $c$ allowed by Einstein's theory of relativity. But $c$ is a far more fundamental constant. It's the constant that links the 3 spatial dimensions to the dimension of time. Literally, in the case of [Minkowski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space).

Comment: You might want to add [this as a reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0302045), which is a more modern retelling of Ignatowski's approach to STR (quite likely,thought, given your answer, you may have seen this reference already).

Answer (score 0):

If we measure weight in units of $c^{2}$, e.g. instead of 10 kg we were to write $90 \cdot 10^{16}$ kg m²/s², then the formula would read $E=m$. Proportionality constants are always a characteristic of the system of units used, not of the actual physical phenomenom. Indeed, in theoretical particle physics it is quite common to work in systems with $c=\hbar=1$.